# __dirname is not defined in NodeJS SocketIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm trying to build from scratch a real time chat app using nodejs(socketio). Currently I am using laravel framework but to continue my project I needed to use nodejs too. This will help me to make my laravel project real time through the use of nodejs socket that's why I'm doing this tutorial from scratch. Just starting to learn this. Using this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHbCkikFfDE

**Here's my server.js code**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
users = [];
connections = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Server running...');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

**Error found**

and when I tried to run the server using this code `node server` the browser where the expected shows this error

```
ReferenceError: _dirname is not defined
at C:\xampp\htdocs\iochat\server.js:12:18
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\iochat\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\iochat\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\xampp\htdocs\iochat\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\iochat\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\iochat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\xampp\htdocs\iochat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\iochat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (C:\xampp\htdocs\iochat\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\iochat\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

In short `__dirname is not defined` How can I solve this one?

Comment: The error says `_dirname` - this means that in your code it's `_dirname`. I just copy-pasted your code into Node and it worked first-time.

Comment: Check number of underscores `_dirname` vs `__dirname`

Comment: Hi guys, I already did that still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks! I just did the cache clear for npm and restart my server.